# Replacing if statement with more flexible solution

Tags: ruby

I have product class with a code as attribute. The code is always a number and according to the first digit the product is of a certain type.

```
If first digit in 0,1,2,3 product is a 'A type'
If first digit in 4,5,6 product is a 'B type'
If first digit in 7,8,9 product is a 'C type'
```

I'm looking for a way to determinate the product type without using a 3 branch `if` statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Check out [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Its already the simplest. Even if you come up with some fancy way, when getting down to machine code level, it will still do something similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

An object-oriented approach. Obviously the `match?` method can be written in whatever way best meets your requirements, as well as adapted as your requirements change—I’ve used regex here to help demonstrate the flexibility of this approach. The `TYPES` constant & `type_for` method should be encapsulated somewhere, but that’s up to you to decide where.

```
class Type
  def initialize name, pattern
    @name = name
    @pattern = pattern
  end

  def match? code
    code =~ @pattern
  end
end

a_type = Type.new 'A', /^[0-3]/
b_type = Type.new 'B', /^[4-6]/
c_type = Type.new 'C', /^[7-9]/
TYPES = [a_type, b_type, c_type]

def type_for product
  TYPES.detect { |type| type.match? product.code }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a `case` statement? I'm not sure if this satisfies your desire to get away from a "3 branch if statement", but maybe it will give you something else to consider.

```
case code[0].to_i
when 0..3 then 'A type'
when 4..6 then 'B type'
when 7..9 then 'C type'
end
```

I'm assuming above that the "code" attribute is actually stored as a string, since you specify that the first digit can be 0, and in Ruby, if it were a literal integer, it would convert your number to octal. If that's a false assumption, just alter the code[0] bit.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the code is stored as a string since actually the code may contain also characters but the first one is always a digit.

The case statement doesn't actually satisfy my desire of "cleanness" since I don't see a great improvement from the if statement.

Comment: +1 for making no assumptions about the relationship between types and codes beyond what was stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use things like this in my own code, simply because I'd rather define a table showing the relationship to the matched value and the expected output:

```
HASH = {
  /\A[0-3]/ => 'A type',
  /\A[4-6]/ => 'B type',
  /\A[7-9]/ => 'C type'
}

def get_type(s)
  HASH.keys.each { |regex| 
    return HASH[regex] if s[regex]
  }
end

[ '0001', '3000', '4000', '9000' ].each do |v|
  puts "#{ v } => #{ get_type(v) }"
end
```

Which outputs:

```
0001 => A type
3000 => A type
4000 => B type
9000 => C type
```

I try to keep things like the hash in a YAML file so we don't have to modify code to add additional tests/types. The HASH constant could easily be initialized using `YAML::load_file()` from a file that looks like:

```
---
? !ruby/regexp /\A[4-6]/
: B type

? !ruby/regexp /\A[0-3]/
: A type

? !ruby/regexp /\A[7-9]/
: C type
```

and gets created with a simple `puts HASH.to_yaml`.

That said, I strongly favor a `case` statement approach also.

Comment: +1 I was considering answering with something like this. Using a hash only to iterate through all of it (never accessing keys individually) seemed weird to me though (not really sure why).

Comment: I don't think it's weird, it's just using a hash for what it is, a mapping of one type of data to another. A similar thing could have been done using sub-arrays, but the `=>` helps act as a visual reminder that the two are bound together for maintenance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(code)
  return 'A type' if code[0] == '0'
  ['A','B','C'][(code[0].to_i-1)/3] << ' type'
end

func('0ekrnn')   # => 'A type'
func('4mgm')     # => 'B type'
```

Comment: This makes assumptions about the relationship between code and type that may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary Operator

```
first_char = code[0].to_i
product_type = [0,1,2,3].include?(first_char) ? "A" : [4,5,6].include?(first_char) ? "B" : [7,8,9].include?(first_char) ? "C" : ""
```

Comment: This is more a "syntax" improvement (if we may call it an improvement) than a "design" improvement. Anyway thanks for your help.